# Add delete button over multiply images

Tags: html, css, typescript, sass, ionic2

I am adding multiple images name with server location as path  `this.Images.push(img);` to   `private images: any[] = [];` to display in `.html`:

```
  <ion-card *ngFor="let i of images">              
    <img [src]="i"/>
  </ion-card>
```

How to add delete button with icon in corner over the image?

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<div class="outer">
  <ion-card class="inner" *ngFor="let i of images">
    <img [src]="i"/>
    <span class="close-icon">X</span>
  </ion-card>
</div>
```

Write the logic to delete image that suits your purpose in deleteImage(i) method.
You can apply css to position the X icon on top corner.

css:

```
.close-icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
 }

.inner {
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
}

.outer {
  height: 90px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Use the below if you are not using font awesome.
     `<span class="close-icon" (click)="deleteImage(i)">X</span>`

Comment: Hello, logic to delete image file from directory on server  is  written, `delImg();` takes particular image name, which can be `i` as in your example like `delImg(i);` and passes it to  `delete.php`, which gets this name and removes image by  location path, but  I'm not sure how properly create `scss` button with x or recycle bin icon   in the corner over the image

Comment: Updated the answer with close icon css.

Comment: I'm new with  `css`,  I added it into `scss` outside of particular gallery page `page-gallery { }` this way `.close-icon{ ... }` and also I have tried it inside like this `page-gallery { .close-icon{ ... }  }` but button does not appears over the images. Not sure what is wrong here. How do you adding `class="fa fa-times close-icon"`? I've tried this way: `fa-fa-times {  .close-icon{  ...    } }` but nothing

Comment: Just add the .close-icon{} in the scss file. Try inspecting this element in browser (developer tools) to see if the styles are applied.   class="fa fa-times close-icon" should be added in the html element.

Comment: I have edited question to show how is done. but I can see `class="fa fa-times close-icon` in html elements of Chrome  browser. File is saved

Comment: with `x` in `<...>x</span>` or `<...>x</i>` it appears not over the each image, but only in one place in top of the page outside the image cards, and with click passes only last image name into delete `delImg(i);` function

Comment: Add a class to ion-card tag and give `position: relative;`.

Comment: I've added  class to ion-card and `position: relative;` to `scss` `.close-icon`, but this way it is  disappeared

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169698/discussion-between-arvind-muthuraman-and-zrubi).

Comment: This answer places all spans 5px away from the top of the page and 5px away from the right. All in the same place.

Comment: Here is the working implementation of my above answer. https://jsfiddle.net/fqdqmLb7/1/

Comment: @Arvind Muthuraman Hello, sorry for late answer, I just missed discussion in chat, thank you. if you are going to edit your answer by this implementation I will mark it as answer